# .htaccess URL rewrite issue. Works on online tester, but not on the hosting server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The URL can be in the format of either:

http://www.example.com/subdomain/123456 or http://www.example.com/123456

I need to rewrite it to:

http://www.example.com/content_pages.php?page=about_us&refferal=123456

I'm using:

```
RewriteRule ^(/?\w*/?)(\d{4,10})$ $1content_pages.php?page=about_us&refferal=$2 [NC,L]
```

It works on then `online RegEx` tester. But gives 404 error on the actual site. Pleaes help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?(\d{4,10})/?$ /$1content_pages.php?page=about_us&refferal=$2 [L,QSA]
```